speechRecognitionLanguage zh-CN Recognizing NOMATCH
I use WebSocket to receive audio stream data captured by the browser.
If I use default English, everything looks good, but when I try to switch languages, it almost cannot recognize any words.
The relevant code is as follows.
...

const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
  process.env.AZURE_SPEECH_SERVICE_KEY || '',
  process.env.AZURE_SPEECH_SERVICE_REGION || '',
)
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = 'zh-CN'
console.log(speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage) // log zh-CN

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  const audioPushStream = PushAudioInputStream.create()
  const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(audioPushStream)
  const speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig)

  speechRecognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => {
    if (e.result.reason == ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech) {
      logger.info(`RECOGNIZING: Text=${e.result.text}`)
    } else if (e.result.reason === ResultReason.NoMatch) {
      logger.info(
        'Recognizing NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized: ' +
          e.result.errorDetails
      )
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unexpected result reason')
    }
  }
  ...
  speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync()
}

info: NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized: undefined
info: NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized: undefined
info: NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized: undefined
info: NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized: undefined

------ websocket processing ------
added 28-08-24 21:02:22
The client mainly captures audio stream and sends the Int16Array data through WebSocket.
The server directly connects the streaming data to the corresponding audioPushStream.
// websocket client
const ws = new WebSocket(import.meta.env.VITE_WS_URL);

async function startRecording(streamId) {
  media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
      }
    },
  });

  // Continue to play the captured audio to the user.
  const output = new AudioContext();
  const source = output.createMediaStreamSource(media);
  source.connect(output.destination);

  // handle audio data
  scriptNode = output.createScriptProcessor(8192, 1, 1);
  source.connect(scriptNode);
  scriptNode.connect(output.destination);
  
  scriptNode.onaudioprocess = async (audioProcessingEvent) => {
    const inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
    const inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    // convert Float32Array to Int16Array
    const intBuffer = new Int16Array(inputData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
      intBuffer[i] = Math.max(-32768, Math.min(32767, Math.round(inputData[i] * 32767)));
    }
    // send audio data
    ws.send(intBuffer.buffer);
  };
}

// websocket server

...
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: port })

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ...
  speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync()
  ws.on('message', (data) => {
    audioPushStream.write(data)
    // ensure audio data is fine
    appendFile('audio.pcm', data, { flag: 'a' })
  })
}


I used the below code and it worked fine for me.
Please note that, I ran it from the C# sample solution at cognitive-services-speech-sdk/samples/csharp/dotnet-windows/console at master.
Note the line setting the SpeechRecognitionLanguage to zh-CN. (Default is en-US).
       public static async Task SpeechRecognitionWithCompressedInputPushStreamAudio()
        {
            // <recognitionWithCompressedInputPushStreamAudio>
            // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("*****", "eastus2");
            config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "zh-CN";
 
            var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
 
            using (var pushStream = AudioInputStream.CreatePushStream(AudioStreamFormat.GetCompressedFormat(AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY)))
            {
                using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(pushStream))
                {
                    // Creates a speech recognizer using audio stream input.
                    using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
                    {
                        // Subscribes to events.
                        recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                        };
 
                        recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                            }
                            else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                            }
                        };
 
                        recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");
 
                            if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                            }
 
                            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                        };
 
                        recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nSession started event.");
                        };
 
                        recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nSession stopped event.");
                            Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                            stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                        };
 
                        // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
                        await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 
                        using (BinaryAudioStreamReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(@"1.wav")))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
                            while (true)
                            {
                                var readSamples = reader.Read(buffer, (uint)buffer.Length);
                                if (readSamples == 0)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                pushStream.Write(buffer, readSamples);
                            }
                        }
                        pushStream.Close();
 
                        // Waits for completion.
                        // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
                        Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
 
                        // Stops recognition.
                        await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }
            // </recognitionWithCompressedInputPushStreamAudio>
        }

Hope this helps.

Thanks for the reply, I noticed that you are using a file stream, but I am using a websocket to receive the audio stream from the browser side, and it seems that the problem is with the websocket handling here.
I have added more code blocks about WebSocket data processing.

Thanks for clarifying. Sharing a few suggestions:

As mentioned in my above sample code, try adding more detailed error handling to capture any specific issues that might be occurring. For example, log the errorDetails from the NoMatch event to get more insights.
Also enable the Speech SDK logging and check if any errors in the logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-use-logging

Hope this helps.

Thank you for your suggestion, I'll give your suggestion a try and if it works out, I will add more details to the issue.
